# Call the function of another contract not on behalf of this contract

Tags: solidity

I have 2 contracts.
For example:
Contract 1

```
contract Token {

  using SafeMath for uint256;

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {
      var test = msg.sender; //msg.sender == address Contract2 
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Contract 2

```
contract Contact2{
    function test() {
          address test = msg.sender; //msg.sender==address my wallets
          Token(0x5faf852d0bae90ae3adb58f68deae7fcfc065a6d).transfer(this, 1);
        }
}
```

When I call test () from the contract2, msg.sender = the address of my wallet. But when running Token(0x5faf852d0bae90ae3adb58f68deae7fcfc065a6d).transfer(this, 1) then msg.sender = address Contract2

As in the contract Token get msg.sender = my wallet?

Comment: I can't grasp the question but transferFrom() could be the answer: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg.sender` is always the account that sent the transaction, in this case it's Contract 1 that is calling `transfer`. As @siid pointed out in the comments, the answer to this issue is the `approve`/`transferFrom` workflow part of the erc20 standard.

Answer (score 0):

You call contract 2 from your wallet, there, msg.sender is your wallet. Contract 2 call contract 1 transfer function, there, msg.sender is the address of contract2.